# Share same variable multiple templates TWIG/SYMFONY

Tags: php, twig, symfony

I would like share some variables into different twig template:

Here's my controller:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    //Get All projects
    $projects = $em->getRepository('WebAwardsBundle:Project')->findAll();

    //Get the Winner of the day
    $winner = $em->getRepository('WebAwardsBundle:Winner')->findBy(
        array('isDay' => '1')
    );
    foreach($winner as $win){
        $idProject = $win->getIdProject();
    }
    $winner = $em->getRepository('WebAwardsBundle:Project')->findById($idProject);

    //Get the author of the project
    $idUser = $winner[0]->getIdAuthor();
    $user = $em->getRepository('WebAwardsBundle:User')->findById($idUser);

    //Get the vote of the project
    $vote = $em->getRepository('WebAwardsBundle:Vote')->findByIdProject($idProject);


    //Get the last project of the Month

    //All Winner of the month
    //Recuperer dans la liste de tous les projets, le projet == meme id, order by date desc limit 1
    return $this->render('project/index.html.twig', array(
        'projects' => $projects,
        'winner'   => $winner,
        'user'     => $user,
        'vote'     => $vote,
    ));
}
```

There's a "winner" object into base.html.twig:

```
<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
            <div class="col-xs-12">- SITE DU MOIS-</div>
            <div class="col-xs-12">{{ winner[0].name }}</div>
            <div class="col-xs-12">- SITE DU MOIS-</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">qsd</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">dqs</div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <p class="text-center">&copy; Copyright 2016 by <a href="{{ path('homepage') }}">WebAwards</a>.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

And here is the login.html.twig where I need the Winner Object:

```
{% block footer %}
    <!-- WINNER IN UNDEFINED :'( -->
    {{ include('base.html.twig', {'winner': winner }) }}
{% endblock %}
```

Does everyone see what's wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that `winner` is passed to `login.html.twig` template? Something like `$this->render('login.html.twig', array('winner' => $winner))` in your controller ?

Comment: Yes sorry, still undefined ...

Comment: Could you show a screenshot of the exception please ?

Comment: Yes : 
http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=153002Capturedecran20160902a180108.png

Comment: @Yonel not sure what you were trying to fix with your edit, but deleting altogether a huge block of code this way looks really bad. Are you trying to deface the question?

Comment: Sorry, I removed a complete block ?? I don't remember that controller block was there before edit the question but only twig templates.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are defining $winner twice, take a look:

```
$winner = $em->getRepository('WebAwardsBundle:Winner')->findBy(
  array('isDay' => '1')
);
...
$winner = $em->getRepository('WebAwardsBundle:Project')->findById($idProject);
```

This definitely doesn't look right!

Comment: Thank you, in fact the first $winner it's the only the id of the winner's project, the second it's the project itself

Comment: Hi. I see you are new to Stackoverflow. If you find any comments useful or helpful, you should click the up triangle. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I fix my trouble  with :

- Create the WinnerDay function in the Winner Controller :

  ```
  public function winnerDayAction(){
  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
  //Get All projects
  $projects = $em->getRepository('WebAwardsBundle:Project')->findAll();

  //Get the Winner of the day
  $winner = $em->getRepository('WebAwardsBundle:Winner')->findBy(
      array('isDay' => '1')
  );
  foreach($winner as $win){
      $idProject = $win->getIdProject();
  }
  $winner = $em->getRepository('WebAwardsBundle:Project')->findById($idProject);
  $userId = $winner[0]->getIdAuthor();
  $user = $em->getRepository('WebAwardsBundle:User')->findById($userId);


  return $this->render('footer.html.twig', array(
      'winner'   => $winner,
      'user'     => $user
  ));`
  ```
- Call the action in the the parent template (base.html.twig)

  ```
  `{{ render(controller('WebAwardsBundle:Winner:winnerDay' )) }}`
  ```
- Finally I created a footer.html.twig where the variable is now available